# Querying model inside 'with'

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm making a chat api in Laravel. I have three models. `User` `Chat` and `Message` and they have their respective tables.

user table

```
id|name|email|other fields
```

chat table

```
id|user_id|receiver_id
```

message table

```
id|chat_id|message|created_at|updated_at|
```

Result is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "chat_id": 5,
            "message": "User 2 to 1",
            "created_at": "2019-02-01 11:32:29",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-01 11:32:29",
            "chat": null
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "chat_id": 1,
            "message": "Sample Chat",
            "created_at": "2019-02-01 10:09:22",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-01 10:09:22",
            "chat": {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": 1,
                "receiver_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2019-02-01 09:41:59",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-01 10:09:22"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "chat_id": 1,
            "message": "Sample Chat",
            "created_at": "2019-02-01 09:42:34",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-01 09:42:34",
            "chat": {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": 1,
                "receiver_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2019-02-01 09:41:59",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-01 10:09:22"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "chat_id": 1,
            "message": "Sample Chat",
            "created_at": "2019-02-01 09:41:59",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-01 09:41:59",
            "chat": {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": 1,
                "receiver_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2019-02-01 09:41:59",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-01 10:09:22"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried

```
$messages = Message::with(['chat' => function($query) use($user){
                        $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
                    }])
                    ->latest()
                    ->get();
```

**As you can see the first data chat model is null.**

I expect to only get all the messages connected to user id from the chat model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use whereHas in your query will give only that chat belongs to purticular user.

```
$messages = Message::with(['chat'])->whereHas('chat', function ($query) {
                     $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
                })
                ->latest()
                ->get();
```